# Using a single sample sequence for estimates of several integrals whose integrands have disjoint support

Tags: monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator, estimators, measure-theory, importance-sampling

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space
- $f:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $\lambda f<\infty$
- $q:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $\lambda q=1$ and $$\{q=0\}\subseteq\{f=0\}\tag1$$
- $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued independent process with $$X_n\sim q\lambda\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag2$$
- $m,n\in\mathbb N$
- $R:=[0,m)\times[0,n)$
- $J:=\{0,\ldots,m-1\}\times\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$
- $h_j:R\to[0,\infty)$ be Borel measurable for $j\in J$
- $\varphi:E\to R$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable

> I'd like to use $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ to estimate $$\Phi_j:=\int(h_j\circ\varphi)f\:{\rm d}\lambda\;\;\;\text{for }j\in J.$$

Now my problem is the specific form of the $h_j$: They are given by $$h_{(s,\:t)}(u):=h\left(u_{(s,\:t)}-u\right)\;\;\;\text{for }u\in R,$$ where $$h(u):=\left.\begin{cases}1&\text{, if }\displaystyle-\frac12\le u_i<\frac12\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }u\in\mathbb R^2$$ and $$u_{(s,\:t)}:=\left(s+\frac12,t+\frac12\right)\in R\;\;\;\text{for }(s,t)\in J.$$

> So, when I'm using the conventional estimator $$\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(h_j\circ\varphi\right)(X_i)\left.\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac fq(X_i)&\text{, if }q(X_i)>0\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\tag3,$$ for $j\in J$, I end up with a nonsensical estimate if $|J|$ is significantly large, since each $\left(h_j\circ\varphi\right)(X_i)$ will vanish for all but a single $j$. Can we form a better estimator? Maybe by conditioning on $\{\left(h_j\circ\varphi\right)(X_i)\ne 0\}$?

**EDIT 1**: For example, I've observed that if $U_n:=\psi(X_n)$ is uniformly distributed on $R$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and I multiply the estimator $(3)$ by the Lebesgue measure of $R$, which is $|J|$, then I end up with a fine estimate. Intuitively, that's plausible, since we can expect that, for each $j$, $\frac n{|J|}$ samples $U_i$ will lie in the support of $h_j$. However, I'm struggling to verify this theoretically. To which estimator does this correspond?

**EDIT 2**: My guess is that we need to consider an estimator build up on the random subsequence $$X^{(j)}_k:=X_{\tau^{(j)}_k}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N_0,$$ where $\tau^{(j)}_0:=0$ and $$\tau^{(j)}_k:=\inf\left\{n>\tau^{(j)}_{k-1}:(h_j\circ\psi)(X_n)>0\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }k\in\mathbb N,$$ for each $j\in J$ separately. I guess we need to replace $(3)$ by $$\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}h\left(X^{(j)}_i\right)\left.\begin{cases}\displaystyle\frac fq\left(X^{(j)}_i\right)&\text{, if }q\left(X^{(j)}_i\right)>0\\0&\text{, otherwise}\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$ Maybe we can show that (in the example described in my first edit) the limit of $(4)$ is off from $\Phi_j$ by a factor of $|J|^{-1}$.

Comment: The issue is in using the same distribution $q$ for all targets $h_j\circ\varphi$'s.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, sure. But suppose there is no other option.

Comment: @Xi'an I'm pretty sure you know the answer to the question in my edit. I'd be great if you could take a look.